# Looking for a specific Harry Potter fanfic featuring an "Elven City"

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

If I remember correctly, Harry went on a journey, during which he found a destroyed city (i believe it was an Elven city).

He restored the city and its people and formed an alliance with them. In the city he received an enchanted weapon and was trained by them. There was some sort of time barrier around the city (eg 10 years in the city = 1 year outside).
Later in the story he saved a young vampire from being raped by a group of vampire hunters, is introduced to her clan and convinces them to join him.

Also he is more powerful than usual, he's a human (no vampire or other) and does not hear any voices in his head.

This work had multiple chapters and of a reasonable length. The fanfic was written in English. It was on fanfiction.net and contained a few scenes involving adult content.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=harry+potter+fanfic+%22elven+city%22+and+%22clan%22+and+%22vampire%22+and+%22alliance%22

Comment: I very much doubt that's all you can remember. Was the story in English?

Comment: Yeah I should have made that clear, it was written in english and had quite a few chapters (long ones, not 3-4 lines per chapter)

Comment: What sites have you read HP fanfics on? When did you read it? Was it "adult" or YA. Aside from Harry, what other characters were present? Was Harry a child or an adult at this point? Who was the young vampire being raped by?

Comment: I believe it was on fanfiction.net. There were a lines that could be described as adult, but they were not too graphic. As for characters, for the most part it was focused on harry and a multitude of new characters

Comment: Can you think of any wording that was specific to the story. Any phrases that appeared in it, or any dialogue that was unique?

Comment: If i recall correctly he was not yet an adult. The attempted rape was commited by a group of vampire hunters I believe

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=inurl:https:%2F%2Fwww.fanfiction.net%2F+%22harry+potter%22+and+%22elf+city%22+and+%22vampire%22 - Elf city

Comment: Not wording specifically, though it was often stressed how respectful and understanding he was to the various characters he met (vampires, elves etc)

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=inurl%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.fanfiction.net%2F%20%22harry%20potter%22%20and%20%22elven%20city%22%20and%20%22vampire%22 - Elven city

Comment: I also remember harry being more powerful than usual. In the city he restored he was given an enchanted sword

Comment: You need to edit all of the above into the question.

Comment: There are a _lot_ of fanfics about this scenario actually, I found 2 that might be it. Can you check them before I answer? [1](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9488265/1/The-Elven-King-and-his-Vampire) and [2](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/1003913/1/Land-of-the-Elves). Note the second is part of a bigger series.

Comment: Hm it could be the first part of nr 2. Let me check it out

Comment: Ok just checked it out, looks interesting, but sadly it's not the right one

Comment: @Reader010 okay, thanks. Not the first one either?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be the fanfiction you meant?

[*Identity*, by 'highbrass'](https://m.fanfiction.net/s/2482703/1/)

<sub>Rated: M, English, Adventure & Romance, Harry P., Fleur D., Words: 167k+, Published: Jul 13, 2005</sub>

**Harry went on a journey, during which he found a destroyed city (i believe it was an Elven city)**

> A city, the most brlliant he had ever seen, lay in ruins. Smoke still rising from burning buildings and the tale-tell flash of shattered wards. Making his was though the destroyed city he couldn't imagine the grandeur it polished white stone and diamond all interwoven wit the forst itself. [...] A city of elves. The girl was one of the last of the race of High Elves left on the planet. - Chapter 5

**He restored the city and its people and formed an alliance with them.**

> His grief turned to rage as he thought of what could have destroyed such a skilled and aged race. Then without caring of the consequences he removed the time turner, [...]  - Chapter 5

On this part I'm not sure if that would work under restoring the city. Since he did technicly like restore the city, by going back in time.

**In the city he received an enchanted weapon and was trained by them.**

> "I was hoping you would consent to train me in the elfin ways of fighting if you had the time to spare." Harry asked. "Of course" [...] The finished product was a weapon so powerful few could wield them effectively. - Chapter 5

In this part he learned over the years how to smith his own weapons and how to enchant them with the help of the elves. While it's not the same as just receiving an enchanted weapon it's still may be the same thing because he learned from them all these years to create this weapon and it was there rescources he used to create this masterpiece.

**here was some sort of time barrier around the city (eg 10 years in the city = 1 year outside).**

> As you have saved mine and my families lives today as well as many of my people it would be an honor to host your stay here as long as you would like. I would like to add that I could change the wards surrounding the city let time pass slower inside than it does outside. You could spend years here and only a day pass in your world. - Chapter 5

**Later in the story he saved a young vampire from being raped by a group of vampire hunters**

> He dashed in and out, down small alway ways, all the time sobs getting louder and louder. The site he came upon as one of revulsion. Five large men carrying multiple weapons were laughing as another was removing a woman's clothing; [...] "We've been sactioned by the Vatican to hunt and remove her kind from this land. Leave now or I will make you!" The elder ground out clearly angered by this boy's idiocy. 'So it was a vampire that these men had down. [...] "This motal saved my life as well as that of the council." - Chapter 3

This may be one of the reason why this isn't the correct one since this place before the elven chapter. But everything else would work fine here

**is introduced to her clan and convinces them to join him.**

> "Any firther attacks on the Vestic clan and I will kill all of you personally" [...] After arriving back in the castle, the Vestic clan held him as a hero. - Chapter 3

This was one of the events where he saved the whole clan and because of this he got the whole support from this clan for anything he requires.

There wasn't really a scene where he got introduced to the whole clan but there was only when he got to meet the leader of her clan.

> "I can be sure because I am the leader, I am Markis leader of the Vestic Clan for the past 1500 years. - Chapter 3

**Also he is more powerful than usual, he's a human (no vampire or other)**

He is more powerful than usual, since he received all this training from all the different races which he visited and learned there magic. He's in many ways way stronger then what he originaly was in the books.